# Trying to select the number of mysql rows inserted yesterday

Tags: mysql

I can normally do this but it appears my brain is not functioning well right now and I'm missing something.

Every day via a cron job that is run at 1am, I want to get a *count of rows* that were inserted yesterday, and the *date*.

ie

```
 SELECT DATE(added) as date, COUNT(*) FROM bookings WHERE added = DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) GROUP BY date
```

'added' contains a timestamp ie '2011-04-18 12:31:31'

What am I getting wrong here? I know there are many rows added yesterday but my query is returning 0 results and no mysql_errors :(

Any ideas?

Comment: what is the datatype of field ADDED?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Please try

```
SELECT DATE(added) as yesterday, COUNT(*) FROM bookings WHERE DATE(added) = DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) GROUP BY yesterday
```

or perhaps

```
SELECT DATE(added) as yesterday, COUNT(*) FROM bookings WHERE DATE(added) = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) GROUP BY yesterday
```

**Updated**
Corrected the WHERE part.

Comment: Thanks for that. But 'Unknown column 'yesterday' in 'where clause''

Comment: your post though gave me the idea to wrap the WHERE 'added' with DATE() ie SELECT DATE(added) as date, COUNT(*) FROM bookings WHERE DATE(added) = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) GROUP BY date

Comment: Ok.. i'll try running it on some data i got.. 2 sec

Comment: Ok my fault ;) I was sure that alias's was available in the where part. I get the same error. Happy that you figured it out :)

Answer (score 2):

well whatever NOW() is will return the time portion and unless they were added at exactly that time the day before they wont be counted.

So either use BETWEEN and specify time range, or format the date in your query to only match on the day month year components and not time

Comment: thanks for this. if I swap NOW() with CURDATE() shouldn't that fix it? I'm still getting 0 results. The challenge is that this will be a cron job that is run at 1am every morning and so the query will need to be dynamic. How do I do a BETWEEN that always works in this method?

Comment: CURDATE still does not equal the values of added

CURDATE() != '2011-06-26 12:31:06" for instance

Comment: Either look at DATE_FORMAT function to format the added values to only be Year Month Day, or use the BETWEEN function to to specify a range within which the added value would sit.

Using DATE_FORMAT on added will mean it cannot use any indexes you may have on there to speed up queries, so BETWEEN may be a better option if performance is a concern

Comment: apologies, yes DATE(added) should just return the Y M D components, so with CURDATE() it should work. Take out the count(*) and group by clause at the moment and change the where clause to DATE(added) <= ...

This should return all records prior to today

Comment: SELECT DATE(added) as date, COUNT(*) FROM bookings WHERE DATE(added) = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) GROUP BY date

Comment: ^ this works for us after changing names to match our columns. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`WHERE added =` does only match exact `NOW() - 1 DAY`, you should select by a range instead.

Comment: I see... but doesn't the DATE() wrapping the 'added' round it down from an exact timestamp to a date?

Comment: No, because you don't compare with the return value of DATE(), see the next answer by Phliplip